# How to translate the text in angular material snackbar using ngx translate

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have implemented ngx translater in my project, I am able to convert the text into other languages which is in HTML page only by having json files, but I want to change the language of the text in "Snackbar" in angular material how can i do that.

my ts file config.

```
       import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
       import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
     

       constructor(public translate: TranslateService,private cookieService: CookieService){
        let cookieValue = this.cookieService.get('lang')
        if(cookieValue){
            translate.setDefaultLang(cookieValue);
            this.browserLang = cookieValue;
        }
        else{
          translate.setDefaultLang('en');
          this.browserLang = translate.getBrowserLang();
        }
        translate.use(this.browserLang.match(/en|es/) ? this.browserLang:'en');
       }
```

HTML:

```
           <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="w-100">
                  <mat-label>Choose Language</mat-label>
                  <mat-select [(value)]="browserLang" #langselect (selectionChange)="translate.use(langselect.value); language_set(langselect.value)">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let lang of languages" [value]="lang.value">
                      {{lang.viewValue}}
                    </mat-option>
                  </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
```

Can anyone help me with this...?

Answer (score 0):

```
snackBar.open(this.translate.intant('your_translation_message'))
```

Comment: 'your_translation_message' i have dynamic text here.. every time it will change...

Answer (score 0):

I have came accorss with the same problem and I decided to load a Component inside Snackbar instead of a text. Of course this means it makes no sense to pass custom messages to the Snackbar but you can pass an enum kind of identifier to the Component to show the message which you want dispaly from a finite list.

You can use openFromComponent() to pass the Component to the Snackbar
https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/overview